# Calculate Days Since Last Event Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This question was answered previously for R. I want to do exactly this but in using pyspark.

make an index of the latest events

```r
last_event_index <- cumsum(df$event) + 1
```

shift it by one to the right

```r
last_event_index <- c(1, last_event_index[1:length(last_event_index) - 1])
```

get the dates of the events and index the vector with the `last_event_index`,
#added an NA as the first date because there was no event

```
last_event_date <- c(as.Date(NA), df[which(df$event==1), "date"])[last_event_index]
```

#substract the event's date with the date of the last event

```r
df$tae <- df$date - last_event_date
df

|        date |event |     tae|
|-------------|------|-------|
|#1 2000-07-06|     0|  NA days
|#2 2000-09-15|     0|  NA days
|#3 2000-10-15|     1|  NA days
|#4 2001-01-03|     0|  80 days
|#5 2001-03-17|     1| 153 days
|#6 2001-05-23|     1|  67 days
|#7 2001-08-26|     0|  95 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Window `last` function to get previous event date then `datediff` with current row date:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

result = df.withColumn(
    "last_event_date",
    F.last(F.when(F.col("event") == 1, F.col("date")), ignorenulls=True).over(w)
).withColumn(
    "tae",
    F.concat(
        F.coalesce(F.datediff("date", "last_event_date"), F.lit("NA")),
        F.lit(" days")
    )
).drop("last_event_date")

result.show()
#+----------+-----+--------+
#|      date|event|     tae|
#+----------+-----+--------+
#|2000-07-06|    0| NA days|
#|2000-09-15|    0| NA days|
#|2000-10-15|    1| NA days|
#|2001-01-03|    0| 80 days|
#|2001-03-17|    1|153 days|
#|2001-05-23|    1| 67 days|
#|2001-08-26|    0| 95 days|
#+----------+-----+--------+
```